# How to get list of channel banned users in telegram?

Tags: python, channel, telegram

I'm looking for list of channel's banned users, but can not find any functions or flags neither in BotAPI nor in CliAPI (i have access to this via pytg). But telegram's mobile app shows this list some way.

Sad to say, i'm not familiar with C++ to look into app's sources. Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

The task is available via Telethon https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon

Comment: please provide the exact method to call because `telethon` is a huge module